# Send-MailMessage multiple recipient

Tags: powershell, email

I try to do a script to send mail to multiple recipients.
I trace to a file the `-To` parameter and it looks OK, but when I send the mail only the second recipient receives the mail.

My script:

```
$mailAddress = $DDSTab2.$clef
$date = Get-Date
Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Value "$date - $Fichier - $mailAddress"
```

Here is example output from the log file:

```
08/29/2017 12:02:13 - PV_00049521_2841_DGFIP_93.pdf - < test@live.com>,< test2@live.com>
```

This doesn't work:

```
Send-MailMessage -From "dgfip@toto.com" -To $mailAddress -Subject "PV $Fichier" -SmtpServer "192.168.40.252" -Body "Veuillez trouver ci-joint le PV de raccordement. Cordialement" -Attachments $PV
```

But when I put the literal recipients it does work:

```
Send-MailMessage -From "dgfip@toto.com" -To <test1@live.com>,<test2@live.com> -Subject "PV $Fichier" -SmtpServer "192.168.40.252" -Body "Veuillez trouver ci-joint le PV de raccordement. Cordialement" -Attachments $PV
```

And it works. I can't understand the problem!

Comment: `-To` expects an array of strings (one string per recipient) - looks like you're supplying a single comma-delimited string with all the recipients

Answer (score 4):

You have pass it as String array.
Try this:

```
$recipients = "test1@live.com", "test2@live.com"

Send-MailMessage -From "dgfip@toto.com" -To $recipients -Subject "PV $Fichier" -SmtpServer "192.168.40.252" -Body "Veuillez trouver ci-joint le PV de raccordement. Cordialement" -Attachments $PV
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: alternative to the string array: `$recipients = @("test1@live.com", "test2@live.com");` Use whichever suits you